# AUTH_ERROR_API_KEY missing after upgrading Glympse Lite SDK from v1.0.10 to 1.0.17

Tags: ios, glympse

After updating the Glympse Lite SDK I am now getting this error in the GlympseLiteWrapper.mm file:

Glympse/GlympseLiteWrapper.mm:88:31: No member named 'AUTH_ERROR_API_KEY' in 'Glympse::LC'

Any ideas how to resolve this?  (If I comment the lines out it does seem to compile but I get some crashes when adding new contacts to Glypmse - not sure if that is related or not but still not sure why I am getting these errors)

I occurs in this switch statement:

```
switch (code->longValue())
    {

        case Glympse::LC::AUTH_ERROR_API_KEY:
        {
            NSLog(@"UNABLE TO RUN PLATFORM: You must pass the Glympse platform a valid API key.");
            break;
        }
        case Glympse::LC::AUTH_ERROR_CREDENTIALS:
        {
            NSLog(@"UNABLE TO RUN PLATFORM: Invalid credentials sent to Glympse server. \
                  Try deleting and reinstalling the app.");
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;

    }
```

Edit:
The crash is related to typing in the letter "T" in the recipient field (see my comment below)   Here is the trace:  ([__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0])

```
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112773f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000110dcabb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011265ef33 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 227
3   HotAir                              0x000000010cd41af0 -[GLYContactsPickerViewController filterSocialCells] + 848
4   HotAir                              0x000000010cd41ea2 -[GLYContactsPickerViewController onSearchTextChanged:] + 178
5   UIKit                               0x000000010e6888be -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 75
6   UIKit                               0x000000010e78f410 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 467
7   UIKit                               0x000000010edc3f3c -[UITextField fieldEditorDidChange:] + 204
8   UIKit                               0x000000010edcc037 -[UITextInputController _sendDelegateChangeNotificationsForText:selection:] + 118
9   UIKit                               0x000000010edcdca9 -[UITextInputController _insertText:fromKeyboard:] + 643
10  UIKit                               0x000000010edce3f5 -[UITextInputController insertText:] + 294
11  UIKit                               0x000000010e87d265 -[UIKeyboardImpl insertText:] + 89
12  UIKit                               0x000000010e879e92 -[UIKeyboardImpl performKeyboardOutput:] + 487
13  UIKit                               0x000000010e879b81 __55-[UIKeyboardImpl handleKeyboardInput:executionContext:]_block_invoke_2 + 116
14  UIKit                               0x000000010ede6914 -[UIKeyboardTaskQueue continueExecutionOnMainThread] + 332
15  Foundation                          0x000000010e22f212 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 299
16  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001126a9551 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011269f41d __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 269
18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011269ea54 __CFRunLoopRun + 868
19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011269e486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
20  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001123869f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
21  UIKit                               0x000000010e687420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
22  HotAir                              0x000000010cbda654 main + 68
23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111218145 start + 1
24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

Comment: Commenting it out should resolve the issue. Crashes you are seeing may not be related. Could you please provide more details on it (stack traces, etc)?

Comment: Sounds good I will comment those out.  I tried creating a separate post about the crash - but I have to wait 90 minutes to post again (due to the lack of reputation).    I have traced the crash down to a very repeatable pattern: when the Glympse dialog is opened if I select the "+" button in the To field to open the Recipients dialog - if I start start a new entry that starts with the letter "T" it crashes the app every time.  If I type anything else it works great.

Comment: I added the trace to the original question.